# Is there anyway to convert those int into time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to convert int into hours:min:sec

```
import datetime 

x = 40000 

t = int(x) 

day = t//86400 
hour = (t-(day*86400))//3600 
min = (t - ((day*86400) + (hour*3600)))//60 
seconds = t - ((day*86400) + (hour*3600) + (min*60)) 

hello= datetime.time(hour.hour, min.minute, seconds.second)   

print (hello )
```

I want this Output:- 11:06:40

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also outsource all the division and modulo operations to Python built-ins (remember: [batteries are included](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0206/#batteries-included-philosophy)!)

```
>>> import time
>>> x = 40000 
>>> time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(x))
'11:06:40'                    # <- that's your desired output
>>> time.gmtime(x)
time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=11, tm_min=6, tm_sec=40, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)
>>> time.gmtime(x).tm_hour    # <- that's how to access individual values
11
```

Answer (score 5):

You almost got it.

`hour`, `min` and `seconds` are integers, and integers don't have `hour`, `minute` or `second` attributes.

Change

```
hello = datetime.time(hour.hour, min.minute, seconds.second)
```

to

```
hello = datetime.time(hour, min, seconds)
```

As a side note, `t = int(x)` is totally unnecessary as `x` is already an `int`.

As a side note 2, in the future please provide the error you receive.

Answer (score 1):

Note: In response to @Pavel's answer,

You may find `time.gmtime(x)` not giving the right time as shown on your pc.

To produce a time consistent with what is on your pc, use `time.localtime(x)` instead

Comment: Since the OP did not specify he was interested in time zone information, I believe `gmtime` is the correct choice in his situation. Using `localtime` will always provide the local offset. Depending on what your time zone is, this means varying answers, specifically in the `hour` component.